# Solving knapsack fractional optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to solve [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

I'm inputing data, and then arrange this data in tuple of list

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = list(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()))
    n, capacity = data[0:2]
    values = data[2:(2 * n + 2):2]
    weights = data[3:(2 * n + 2):2]
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values)
```

My input

```
3 40
20 50
40 60
50 60
```

My tuple:

```
[(20, 50), (40, 60), (50, 60)]
```

Then I'm sorting it by highest value of values//weight. Next I'm implementing algorithm.

```
def get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values):
    ziplist = list(zip(values, weights))

    newlist = sorted(ziplist, key = lambda x : x[0] / x[1], reverse = True)

    m = capacity

    while (m != 0):
        for i in range(0,len(newlist)):
            a = min(newlist[i][1],capacity)
            value = a * newlist[i][0]/newlist[i][1]
            m -= newlist[i][1]


    return m
```

My strategy:

1. I'm work until capacity of knapsack would be 0
2. If weight in first list of sorted tuple is less than capacity of knapsack, I decrease capacity of knapsack by weight of this element and increase value by element value
3. Do this step with next element of tuple until capacity would be 0
4. If weight in the first list of sorted tuple is more than capacity of knapsack, then I need to add to value variable the proportion of weight to capacity

But when I run function returns nothing - what is the problem?

Comment: `m` goes below 0 in the for so your loop never ends, also you never use value

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you please explain, why it goes below 0, wouldn't it stopped, when reaching 0?

Comment: You only check in the outer loop so if `m` goes below 0 in the for loop then it is too late to check for `0` as you are < 0, which algorithm are you trying to implement, greedy?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes,greedy

Comment: This might be closer to what you want http://pastebin.com/kPuj2cu4